# Fetch depreciation warning for window.fetch() ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs

Even though, I am catching the catch() error. I continue to get the depreciation notice that states **UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either from** How do I fix this error?

Full error

```
node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "Error: FetchError: invalid json response body at undefined reason: Unexpected end of JSON input".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}

addPokemonToList = () => {
    window
      .fetch('/all/pokemons', {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          pokemon_id: this.props.pokemonId,
          trainer_id: this.props.trainerId,
          search_id: this.props.searchId ? this.props.searchId : undefined,
          [getCsrfParam()]: getCsrfToken(),
        }),
      })
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(json =>
        this.setState({
          success: json.success,
          PokemonChoiceId: json.pokemonChoiceId,
        })
      )
      .catch(err => {
        throw new Error(err);
      });
  };
```

Comment: Try update from `.throw new Error(err);` to `console.log(err)` to see the error.

Comment: Can you add full error message

Comment: one moment please

Comment: Can you change `.then(resp => resp.json())` this line to `.then(resp => console.log(resp))` and what is the output.

Comment: Doesn't reach an output -- it simply gives the same error.

Comment: Is `getCsrfParam` and `getCsrfToken` function using promise or async await

Comment: export function getCsrfToken() {
 const contentTag: ?HTMLElement = document.querySelector('meta[name=csrf-token]');
if(tag && tag instanceof window.HTMLMetaElement) {
return tag.content;
} else {
 return '';
}}

Comment: it doesn't seem to return a promise/async await..... @kennarddh

Comment: Can console log the body

Comment: Give me about 15 minutes.